# What's normal practice with git and websites? The repository in the web root?

Tags: git, svn

I've been used to subversion, so this isn't obvious to me.

Say I have a website at **www.example.com**, not currently under source control, which I want to control with git.

I want to make changes at say **dev.example.com** and commit them when I'm confident they work.

How do people normally do this? I've been doing a bit of reading it seems the normal practice is to create the git repo right there at the root of **www.example.com**, then pull to dev. Is that right? Or is it safer, or better practice, to have both **www** and **dev** as working trees and the repo at some third place?

Comment: have www & dev as separate branches, work on them & merge the 2 and  push when done

Comment: I have `repo.example.com` for my git repos, which has a hook that pushes updates to `beta.example.com`.  I test from there and sync it over to `example.com` when I have had the ability to test enough to move it over (of course, I have LAMP locally to do work and avoid 500 commits for little things).  Is it the best way, not sure - but it has worked well for my uses.  I dislike cluttered folders though.

Answer (score 2):

Since git is distributed, you don't necessarily have to have the repo somewhere other than dev or www.

A good practice is to use dev as your working tree, create tags and push those tags to www.

With git, your ideal workflow should be relatively more frequent, smaller commits - you can always rebase to clean up your commit history before pushing it to a central repo / www.

In a larger organization, you would have a 'repo of record' that would be managed by your release engineer(s).  For a small / one-person team, then you'll know when you want to push your repo to www.

Do *not* make www your working tree.  All of your changes should come from the repo - this will ensure your production server is always in a known state.